# running pdftk in bash from python script

Tags: python, bash, pdftk

I try to call pdftk from python script in 2 ways. None of them works.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-

from __future__ import print_function
import subprocess
#import sh

subprocess.call("pdftk File.pdf cat {2,3} output zmiana.pdf", shell=True)
sh.pdftk(File.pdf cat {1,3,2,4} output zmiana.pdf)
```

the output of the first is :

```
Error: Unexpected text in page range end, here: 
   {2,3}
   Exiting.
   Acceptable keywords, for example: "even" or "odd".
   To rotate pages, use: "north" "south" "east"
       "west" "left" "right" or "down"
```

while the second:

```
sh.pdftk(File.pdf cat {1,3,2,4} output zmiana.pdf)
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

what did I do wrong?

Comment: The second obviously fails (it's a Python syntax error). Regarding the first form, it's a pdftk error: have you tried `pdftk File.pdf cat 2-3 output zmiana.pdf` instead? (without the curly braces)

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf For the first: calling directly what is written inside "" works in terminal. Changing to 2-3 doesn't fit me, because at the end I would like to have something like {1,3,2,4} in that order. 
Do you have idea how to correct the second?

Comment: Just give your pages to pdftk: `pdftk File.pdf 1 2 3 4 output zmiana.pdf`. You can also do: `subprocess.call("pdftk File.pdf cat %s output zmiana.pdf" % ' '.join(map(str, pages)), shell=True)` where `pages` is a list (or iterable) of integers. E.g., `pages = (1, 2, 3, 4)`.

Answer (score 2):

The following python script worked for me (adding a cover page to scanned exams;
all attempts to try PyPDF2 failed as the scanned pdf file was somehow corrupted)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
 # -*- coding: utf8 -*-

import subprocess

subprocess.call('pdftk A="D:/xxx/coverpage.pdf"   B="D:/xxx/exam.pdf" cat A1 B   output "D:/xxx/examcov.pdf" ', shell=True)
```